ということとか VS こととか
In the following extract, is there a reason why っていうこととか is used for the first circumstance, while simply こととか is used for the second circumstance?

[...]
そういう色々制限は、コロナの人は増えたけど、前よりも制限が少なくなってますね。ま、これも、やっぱり、ワクチンを打つ人が多くなって、そして、以前よりもコロナにかかっても重症になりにくいっていうこととか、コロナの薬が出来たこととか、そういうのが関係しているんでしょうね。

Context: the text above is my transcription from a podcast for learners of Japanese. The topic is "Recent news in Japan". At the time, Coronavirus cases were still high, but restrictions had loosened a bit.

“って (+こととか）” is a colloquial expression often used when quoting or referring to an idea or concept. By using “っていう," the speaker gives the impression of maintaining some distance from the information or concept. It indicates an attitude of conveying what is generally said rather than making a direct assertion.
The second “こととか” is a more direct statement of fact. It does not require the nuance of “quoting” or “referring” as much as the first point.

I see. Thank you, I appreciate your help!
